508 compliance InDesign table: set text to apply 'alt text' to override the original text for screen reader?
Revising an InDesign doc for 508C compliance, I'm stuck on a Table where:

It has 3 columns where headers are set to row 1.
First row : Column 1 & 2's header just contain the text 'Yes' and 'No'.
The following rows under column 1 & 2 contains just checkboxes (created from Zapf dingbats char) and the 3rd columns a statement/question of Yes/No value, to correspond to the checkboxes.

Can I (and how to) treat these checkboxes as images and get an 'alt text' option for them? Or is there another way to call out selected text (Zapf dingbats) to give it specific meaning to a screenreader?

Indesign generally doesn't output PDFs which are accessible. The resulted PDF needs heavy edits in Acrobat to stop to raise red or yellow error flags in advanced formal inspectors like PAC. Passing Adobe's inspector means NOTHING. Often it's easier to skip all tagging in Indesign and remediate the PDF 100% in Acrobat . Is your form with checkboxes an interactive form or is it only an image of a printable form? Insert the form as an image to your question - change the texts if needed to keep the actual content secret.

This is for print, so they just have to visually display a square box.

Graphic items (lines, dashed lines, boxes ) which are built of characters are common in lists and forms. Using them is begging troubles if one wants to make an accessible PDF. You said you have dingbats, which actually are text.
In accessible PDFs all text should be either tagged to belong to some structure element or they should be marked to be artifacts.
Giving tag "Figure" to an item which contains characters is also begging troubles. Advanced  accessibility inspecting programs raise something like "serious warning, text marked to be an image!" There can also easily appear "Fatal error, insufficient color contrast!" if the text in the image is a little faint or has too small size for the used colors.
It's best to convert all text in images to curves and to do the same to texts which actually are graphic items.
My suggestion: Convert the whole image of the form to curves or to high resolution raster image. Tag it to be a figure. Be sure that the layout contains a preceding explanation text (Caption) which tells that this is the image of the printable paper form (name, possible identifier number and short content description).
Tag the image to be a Figure. Insert an alt text which tells for every field what's asked and possible selectable alternatives. Write everything in the most logical filling order. The alt text can be long, but that's no reason to leave it out.
Some PDF reading programs are so dumb that they do not show the existence of the alt text if the image contains only vector shapes. Insert below everything a white PNG image to make the figure to have also bitmap content to pop up the alt text when the mouse hovers over. This trick has stopped much unnecessary nagging; without it the customer said to me "this cannot be accessible; I cannot see alt texts! I am not going pay before it's fixed!"
Today it's increasingly common that people who check if a PDF is accessible  use advanced accessibility checkers. One of them is PAC, mentioned in a comment above. Making something which satisfy PAC users really needs some care and knowledge, because Indesign leaves out so much. For example object attribute Placement\Block or \Inline must often be inserted manually to tags Figure, Link and Form.
Tagging a fillable form is not tricky assuming the form is built by thinking the tagging beforehand. But that's not the problem in this question.
